# installing mod_ssl amazon linux

Tags: linux, ssl, amazon-web-services, centos

I'm simply trying to install `mod_ssl` on a CentOS server. Doing a straightforward `sudo yum install mod_ssl` would return an error:

> Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with
>   httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
>
> Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I tried to remove `httpd-tools` by: `sudo yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64` but no luck. Is there any things that I missed?

**EDIT**:

I did `sudo yum -v remove httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64` and outputs this:

```
Yum Version: 3.2.29
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
Setting up Package Sacks
amzn-main                                                                                                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
pkgsack time: 0.330
Package(s) httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Doing `yum search mod_ssl` outputs this:

[image]

Comment: What is the yum output from `yum -v remove httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64` looks like a dependency problem. You may have to remove php at the same time and install the newer version compatible with httpd24-tools

Comment: could you provide the [AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) id that is used so I can fire one up and look into it. Also does `rpm -qa  |grep http` output?

Comment: @MattGreen - how can I know that via SSH? Yes it does, here `httpd24-2.4.6-2.48.amzn1.x86_64
perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.02-4.2.amzn1.noarch
httpd24-tools-2.4.6-2.48.amzn1.x86_64`

Comment: from the above you have httpd24-2.4.6-2.48.amzn1.x86_64 and httpd24-tools-2.4.6-2.48.amzn1.x86_64 installed so that is not the issue here. They must be using custom repos on the instances. What is the output from yum search mod_ssl?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install mod24_ssl
```

If you run into another incompatibility like this in the future, use `yum search all`. For example:

```
yum search all mod_ssl
```

Returns:

```
mod_ssl.x86_64 : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod24_ssl.x86_64 : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and solved it simply by [compiling Apache version 2.4.6](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html) from source with the [Amazon APR Devel](https://apr.apache.org/compiling_unix.html) package 1.4.6 that is in the AMI and then copied the newly compiled `mod_ssl.so` to the `/etc/httpd/modules` directory, that's it.

[Here you can download](https://github.com/DSPEED/mod_ssl.2.4.6_x64_amzlnx?source=c) the `mod_ssl.so` for *Amazon Linux Apache 2.4.6 x64 MOD_SSL* Package.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any missing modules by using APXS

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apxs.html

Download that package, upload to your server, follow the instructions normally. If you run into errors it just means you have to install the missing components. In my case i had to install libtools and openssl.

Just use something like:

> sudo yum install libtools

I believe you also need apache developer tools, you can easily find the installable things by doing

> sudo yum search httpd-dev

for example (not quite sure about this one)

lastly just follow the instructions from the link i pasted at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

this one may help you :

In Ubuntu 18.04, please search mod_ssl by 
`apt search mod_ssl` then you see `apache2-ssl-dev`, this one is what you need.