# install mod_ssl issue apache 2.4 aws linux

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, centos, redhat, apache2.4

Using aws Linux .   When I try to install mod_ssl its give a conflict error with ttpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 and  httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64.  Tried yum remove but it's not working.  When I do a yum list the old httpd version is not getting listed. Not sure why is it.  Could anyone help me out regarding this.

```
 [root@ip-61 ec2-user]# yum install mod_ssl
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.31-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.31-1.8.amzn1 for package: 1:mod_ssl-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: 1:mod_ssl-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.31-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.31-1.8.amzn1 for package: httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: apr-util-ldap for package: httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr-util-ldap.x86_64 0:1.4.1-4.17.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.31-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.18-1.64.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.18
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd24.x86_64 0:2.4.18-1.64.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package httpd24.x86_64 0:2.4.23-1.66.amzn1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: httpd24-tools = 2.4.23-1.66.amzn1 for package: httpd24-2.4.23-1.66.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd24-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.18-1.64.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package httpd24-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.23-1.66.amzn1 will be an update
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.23-1.66.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.23
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.23-1.66.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.23
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@ip-61 ec2-user]# yum l

[root@ip-61 ec2-user]# yum list installed | grep -in httpd
120:httpd24.x86_64                    2.4.18-1.64.amzn1                @amzn-main
121:httpd24-tools.x86_64              2.4.18-1.64.amzn1                @amzn-main


[root@ip-61 ec2-user]# yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
No Packages marked for removal

[root@ip-61 ec2-user]# yum remove httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
No Packages marked for removal
[root@ip-61 ec2-user]#
```

]# yum list installed | grep -in httpd
120:httpd24.x86_64                    2.4.18-1.64.amzn1                @amzn-main
121:httpd24-tools.x86_64              2.4.18-1.64.amzn1                @amzn-main

Comment: Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing mod\_ssl amazon linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646150/installing-mod-ssl-amazon-linux)

Answer (score 6):

Basically: sudo yum install mod24_ssl

Not taking credit for this though, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21781886

Comment: for the perplexed, it's actually `sudo yum install mod24_ssl`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command

```
yum install mod24_ssl.x86_64
```

It will be installing mod_ssl without any dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something like cpanel or plesk or directadmin installed, they added a bunch of exclude= lines to /etc/yum.conf, ex:

```
exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*
```

and stop various packages from being installed. They do this because they supply their own versions of many central CentOS packages and want to stop the CentOS ones from overwriting them. Once you install a web panel like this, you have changed the way the system operates and you have to go to them to ask how to install things as the normal CentOS ways would end up breaking their other installed packages.

I found this answer on internet

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-install using

yum remove < all listed packages>

yum install mod_ssl

Comment: Have tried  yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64  and yum remove httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64  did a  yum install mod_ssl but still it doesnt work