# I am having problems installing mod_ssl onto my AWS Apache instance

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-ssl

I am having problems installing mod_ssl onto my AWS Apache instance...

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-185 ~]$ yum install mod_ssl
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
You need to be root to perform this command.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-185 ~]$ sudo yum install mod_ssl
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: 1:mod_ssl-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 for package: 1:mod_ssl-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 for package: httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: apr-util-ldap for package: httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr-util-ldap.x86_64 0:1.5.4-6.18.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.33-2.78.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.33
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.33-2.78.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.33
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-185 ~]$
```

I have tried running sudo yum install 24mod_ssl to no avail? It says No package 24mod_ssl available.

What can I do?

Comment: **mod24**_ssl, not 24mod. See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646150/installing-mod-ssl-amazon-linux/21781886#21781886](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646150/installing-mod-ssl-amazon-linux/21781886#21781886)

Answer (score 8):

In case someone has missed Andra's comment above, like I did the first time I looked at this post:

To solve the conflict you are having install the following module instead:

sudo yum install mod24_ssl.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Your apache modules is conflicting. see here
httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64. It looks like you have chose pre installed apache AMI and have installed apache again on it.